# Having Trouble Optimizing One KPI based on results of multiple KPI's

Tags: r, optimization, regression

This is going to be a general question that can be open to further discussion:

I have a Metric/KPI and my goal is to increase it to above $20. There are 10 other Metrics/KPI's in this dataset that I need to change in order for this to happen.

I have tried multiple regression where I did the following:

1. Created a correlation matrix to determine bivariate relationships in comparison to the metric I want to raise to above $20.
2. I took the significant metrics based off of their correlation values and plugged the metrics into a multiple regression equation.
3. From there, I did stepwise to remove collinearity
4. Re-did the equation
5. Then removed any non-signifcant KPI's based on P-Values.
6. Now I have my regression equation.

Here's my dilemma:

I now have a regression equation, how do I determine the optimal values for each variable in the equation to get my response variable above $20?

I got the following as my answer:

```
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        -0.29846    0.08793  -3.394 0.000703
A1                  0.46484    0.16564   2.806 0.005064
A                 -13.67332    0.29319 -46.636  < 2e-16
B                   7.57238    0.06437 117.643  < 2e-16
C                   2.97253    0.27463  10.824  < 2e-16
D                   1.69753    0.02918  58.175  < 2e-16
```

Each of these variables is a formula based on other metrics (Metrics not in the equation directly). So for example,

```
A = E/F
B = E/G
C = E/H
D = E/(H*I)

Main KPI we want over $20 = (J/H)*1000
```

This kind of question doesn't require that much R code for help because I am really just trying to get this concept down.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal values? Are there any cost functions associated with those variables? if not, any solution that raises it above $20 is optimal right?

Comment: Just added some functions @Shape. I am really just trying to see if my concept is right and if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Could this also be converted into a linear programming problem?

Comment: So, you have some equation which represents a manifold, take derivatives and find the maxima? If you have a set of conditions (or even just the condition that they should add to above 20), then lagrange multipliers seems like a plan but you could have infinite solutions. Right now, I don't see what control you have over the values here. What's to stop you from, say making J very large? Is J a constant?

Comment: J is Revenue which is contingent on A*Another Metric

Comment: Also how would I take the derivative of this if it isn't quadratic? @Shape

Comment: The search for optimality comes down to reducing your degrees of freedom. If you want to do linear programming, then you need to know the costs associated with adjusting each value. If you have a set of bounds then find all the parameters with a positive relationship to the metric and set them to the maximum value, and set all the ones with an inverse relationship to the minimum.  If it's not at least quadratic in any of the parameters, and you don't have any cost functions associated with them, you have infinite freedom.